# Exporting jar file from vscode, The jar file does not open

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, jar, vscode-extensions, executable-jar

If I Exported a file jar from IntelliJ and opened it work perfectly but if do this in vscode after exporting the file with no errors I can't open the file I click on the jar file and nothing happening ,I extract the both files jar the one from IntelliJ and the vscode one ( to look at the files in side jar file ) both had the same files and same MANIFEST.MF file so why the IntelliJ work but vscode one doesn't ?

NOTES:

1. java -version: "17.0.1" and javac -version: 17.0.1 (no problem with versions).
2. If I tried to open jar file with terminal not by clicking I got this Error:

   ```
    "Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class App
    java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Preview features are not enabled 
    for App (class file version 61.65535). Try running with '--enable-preview'"
   ```

Comment: Did you try `—enable-preview`?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Thank you I tried it and it works but I tried it in the terminal (CMD) by typing : "java --enable-preview -jar [File_Name].jar", can I make it works just when I click on the icon (with out terminal)?

Comment: Configure Vscode not to use preview features from the jdk and reexport.

Comment: ok I got you but I can't find the place in vscode settings that I can use --enable-preview so if you know tell me please,Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I found is by creating a .bat file and write this code in it :
`java --enable-preview -jar <filename>.jar`
now you can run the .jar file by running the generated .bat file

Comment: can you accept this answer to mark the question as resolved?

Comment: @MollyWang-MSFT Yes I tried but I got this message : "You can accept your own answer tomorrow", so I will do it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Preview features are enabled by default. Configure the `java.configuration.runtimes` preference in your **User Settings.json**:

```
"java.configuration.runtimes": [
  {
    "name": "JavaSE-17",
    "path": "/path/to/jdk-17",
    "default": true
  },
],
```

Then reload window and try again.

**Reference:** [Enabling Java preview features](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/Enabling-Java-preview-features)

Comment: it did not work : I did what you said and add the this configuration I set the path to my jdk path in windows no errors , reload my vscode, export the jar file and run it again but same problem.
But I solved my problem by creating a .bat file with java --enable-preview -jar <filename>.jar
If you have a better solution tell me please and thank you for answering my question :)

Comment: @AbodShashtari. You may write down your solution for people with similar issues to reach. :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the current version of Language Support for Java will not add `--enable-preview` argument when compiling with Java 17, it will happen when you're using Java 18, so could you provide more information, such as

- the version of your Language Support for Java
- the argument passed to the compiler (if you just compile the project manually)

Comment: I use this extension Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat v1.2.0 it says "Supports code from Java 1.5 to Java 17" and as I mentioned that I use java 17 ( I don't know if there is java 18 ) and no not manually I didn't pass any argument and I used this way to export my java code to .jar file https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project